# Can't save a record twice, because of this error: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm working on a program that inserts and deletes data into a database. The database only have one table with four columns (nombreEmpleados, apellidosEmpleados, departamento and carnet). The program has 4 buttons, save, delete, show and close, the problem is that when I click show or save the first time, the program works, but when I do it again I get this error: ***The connectionstring property has not been initialized***.

***EDIT***
***This is code from the begining to the save button:  ***

```
namespace sampleAdonetWinforms
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MAINPC;Initial Catalog=Ambar;Integrated Security=True");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formBorrar ventanaBorrar = new formBorrar();
        ventanaBorrar.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (@Nombre, @Apellidos, @Departamento, @Carnet)";
        SqlCommand vCom = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        int carnetID = int.Parse(tbCarnet.Text);

            try
            {
                vCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", tbNombre.Text);
                vCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellidos", tbApellidos.Text);
                vCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Departamento", tbDepartamento.Text);
                vCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Carnet", carnetID);
                tbNombre.Focus();
                conn.Open();
                vCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
                vCom.Dispose();
                MessageBox.Show("Data stored");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex.Message);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Where have you declared and initialized `conn`?

Comment: Where do you create the connection object that you use in the code? That's where the connection string should be set.

Comment: A global connection object is the perfect recipe for any kind of disasters. Don't do that. Declare, initialize, open, use, close and dispose a connection object in the same spot where do you need it

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I edited the post, so you can see where I declared it.

Comment: @Steve: I did it based on a tutorial that I watched in youtube yesterday, so I though it was right. Thanks for the advice, I'm gonna do it.

Comment: Another question, when you click the button to save, the form close and you need to reopen it to insert a new record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have said in my comment, the global SqlConnection object could be the origin of your problems.
From your code is not evident, but something, at the second passage doesn't work as expected and the global connection object is not correctly initialized.
Keeping a global instance of a connection object is a bad practice because you risk to loose control on the lifetime of that instance and precious unmanaged resources are not released to the system.
To cure this kind of problem there is the [Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) infrastructure.
The Connection Pooling helps to implement a coding pattern where the coder should release as soon as possible the connection.

So I suggest to change your code to take advantage of this pattern

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // INITIALIZE 
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("......"))
    {
         // OPEN
         conn.Open();
         string query = "INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (@Nombre, @Apellidos, @Departamento, @Carnet)";
         // USE
         using(SqlCommand vCom = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
         {
             ....
         }
    } // <- CLOSE & DISPOSE
}
```

Comment: Then, everytime I have to use a connection I will have to initialize it in every method I need it?

PD: Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, the connection pooling will help to reduce the impact on the performances because it keeps a connection ready available for you if you recall it with the same connection string. The only thing that is safe to keep global is the connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Try the creating a `SqlConnection` object. I'm unsure if you do that globally and then opening the connection after passing it to the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO empleados VALUES (@Nombre, @Apellidos, @Departamento, @Carnet)";
        SqlCommand vCom = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

conn.Open();
```

`conn` must be created like this before the `conn` is passed to the `SqlCommand` object

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connection string from config file");
```

Comment: I create the sqlconnection object, the thing is that I couldn't find a reason why it didn't worked.